# Digest URI mismatch with proxy

Tags: apache, .htaccess, digest-authentication

I have two servers on my network. One has an external IP, the other internal only. I have my server setup so that going to http://my.site.com/Motes/ actually goes to the root of the internal server at address 192.168.1.102, like so:

httpd.conf of outward facing server:

```
ProxyPass /Motes/ http://192.168.1.102/
ProxyPassReverse /Motes/ http://192.168.1.102/



<Proxy  http://192.168.1.102/*>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "Motes"
    AuthDigestDomain /
    AuthDigestProvider file
    AuthUserFile ps.wd
    AuthGroupFile group.file
    Require group usergroup
</Proxy>
```

This works until I turn on Digest authentication on the interal server by adding:

```
AuthType Digest
AuthName "Motes"
AuthDigestDomain / /Motes/
AuthDigestProvider file
AuthUserFile ps.wd
AuthGroupFile group.file
Require group usergroup
```

to the other internal server root .htaccess file. Then my internal servers complains about:

```
[Sat May 04 09:37:32 2013] [error] [client ***.***.***.***] Digest: uri mismatch - </Motes/> does not match request-uri </>
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I fixed this by adding a new CNAME for my internal server that my external facing server proxied directly to the internal server, in essence a proxied virtual host.

```
<virtualhost *:80>
ServerName internal.site.com

ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.102:80/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.102:80/
<Proxy http://192.168.1.102:80/* >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
    Satisfy Any 
</Proxy>

</virtualhost>
```

Then the internal server enforces digest authentication like in the question.

Comment: what do you mean by 'CNAME'?  I'm having exact same problem

Comment: a CNAME record with your DNS host, an 'A' record would work as well. Essentially, I went from using http://my.site.com/Motes/ to using http://internal.site.com/ and setting up a virtual host in the vhost.conf file in the 'extras' folder under the 'config' folder.